# VPN provider for remote access to servers from a known IP address

Tags: vpn, remote-access

My organization has a few servers that are being hosted by a provider and we limit remote access to a whitelist and deny access to any IPs not on the whitelist.  We would like to find a hosted VPN service that we can connect to that would give us a known IP that we could add to our whitelist and gain access to the servers while on the road.

Does anyone know of any such services?

I don't think we can just setup the VPN built in to Windows Server since the servers are hosted. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just just open up access from anywhere.  It sounds to me like you are just making things needlessly complex without adding much value.  What value is there in limiting access to specific hosts, and then setting up a proxy so you aren't limited to access from specific hosts?  Can you just setup a lightweight VPN (ssh/stunnel) on one of your servers if you are worried about transport encryption?

Comment: Have you tried to set up the VPN on the servers? There's no point in guesswork. I can't see why the server being hosted should make any difference. Try it and then make a decision based on the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, we ended up using the Cisco VPN client provided by our hosting company for a VPN solution.  We have to use internal network addresses to access our servers when connected to the VPN because of the split-tunneling on the VPN client, bit it's really not much of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Not used then, but you could talk to:

- http://www.hosted-vpn.com/ms/
- http://www.gotoservers.com/

Answer (score 0):

K-Secure VPN will probably serve your needs best. It provides an easy solution for setup and maintenance. Our company deployed this product and it works great for us.